# filter pandas dataframe based in another column

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, slice

this might be a basic question, but I have not being able to find a solution. I have two dataframes, with identical rows and columns, called Volumes and Prices, which are like this

**Volumes**

```
Index    ProductA    ProductB     ProductC     ProductD    Limit
0          100          300          400           78       100
1          110          370           20           30       100
2           90          320          200          121       100
3          150          320          410           99       100
....
```

**Prices**

```
Index    ProductA    ProductB     ProductC     ProductD    Limit
0           50          110          30           90        0
1           51          110          29           99        0
2           49          120          25           88        0
3           51          110          22           96        0
....
```

I want to assign 0 to the "cell" of the Prices dataframe which correspond to Volumes less than what it is on the Limit column

so, the ideal output would be

**Prices**

```
Index    ProductA    ProductB     ProductC     ProductD    Limit
0           50          110          30            0         0
1           51          110           0            0         0
2            0          120          25           88         0
3           51          110          22            0         0
....
```

I tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d_price = {'ProductA' : [50, 51, 49, 51], 'ProductB' : [110,110,120,110], 
'ProductC' : [30,29,25,22],'ProductD' : [90,99,88,96], 'Limit': [0]*4}
d_volume = {'ProductA' : [100,110,90,150], 'ProductB' : [300,370,320,320], 
'ProductC' : [400,20,200,410],'ProductD' : [78,30,121,99], 'Limit': [100]*4}
Prices = pd.DataFrame(d_price)
Volumes = pd.DataFrame(d_volume)

Prices[Volumes > Volumes.Limit]=0
```

but I do not obtain any changes to the Prices dataframe... obviously I'm having a hard time understanding boolean slicing, any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
Prices[Volumes > Volumes.Limit]=0
```

Since Limit varies on each row, you should use, for example, apply like following:

```
Prices[Volumes.apply(lambda x : x>x.Limit, axis=1)]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mask to solve this problem, I am not an expert either but this solutions does what you want to do.

```
test=(Volumes.ix[:,'ProductA':'ProductD'] >= Volumes.Limit.values)
final = Prices[test].fillna(0)
```